# LookUp by Attribute Group Instead of Specific Data Extension

Tags: email, journeybuilder, dataextensions, contactbuilder, attribute-group

In **Salesforce Marketing Cloud**, I have the following:

**Data_Extension_1**

```
Subscriber Key (Primary Key)
Email (Email Address)
```

**Data_Extension_2**

```
Subscriber Key (Primary Key)
Gender (Boolean)
Fav Movie (Text)
```

I Created an attribute group called **My_Relationship** which does a 1-1 relationship between `contact key and subscriber key (DE1)` and then a 1-1 relationship between `subscriber key (DE1) to subscriber key (DE2)`. This in turn allows me to use `Gender` as a decision split in my journey.

To dynamically looking up values in the template:

```
%%[
var @Email, @Gender, @FavMovie, @lookupValue
set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("Subscriber Key")
set @Email = Lookup("Data_Extension_1","Email","Subscriber Key", @lookupValue)
set @Gender = Lookup("Data_Extension_2","Gender","Subscriber Key", @lookupValue)
set @FavMovie = Lookup("Data_Extension_2","Fav Movie","Subscriber Key", @lookupValue)
]%%
```

I can display the values with:

```
<span>
  <strong>Email</strong>: %%=v(@Email)=%%
  <strong>Gender</strong>: %%=v(@Gender)=%%
  <strong>Favorite Movie</strong>: %%=v(@FavMovie)=%%
</span>
```

---

**My Question**

Is there any way to use the **Attribute Group** that i created called **My_Relationship**, so that i do not directly have to LookUp the data extensions by name: **Data_Extension_1**/**Data_Extension_2**. Basically, I don't care and I don't want to know the data extension name, I created a relationship for a reason and there shouldn't be any duplicate field names; as such in theory i should be able to retrieve the value by looking at the **Attribute Group**.

E.g.

```
%%[
var @Email, @Gender, @FavMovie, @lookupValue
set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("Subscriber Key")
set @Email = Lookup("My_Relationship","Email","Subscriber Key", @lookupValue)
set @Gender = Lookup("My_Relationship","Gender","Subscriber Key", @lookupValue)
set @FavMovie = Lookup("My_Relationship","Fav Movie","Subscriber Key", @lookupValue)
]%%
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Data Designer (attribute groups) are only used in Journey builder (decision splits/entry filters) and mobile filtered lists

Comment: @EazyE is there anyway to achieve what OP is trying to do in SFMC. Maybe Attribute Groups isn't the right thing to use but is there something else that can give a comparable result?

Comment: As EazyE says, the contact model can't be used for this. You could just use Profile Attributes, though, rather than using Data Extension fields to store these lookup values in. You could then grab these values along the lines of SET @favmovie = [Fav Movie] or personalise with %%Fav Movie%%.